# how to simulate aloha protocol using a programming language?

Tags: protocols

I'm new to networking in general and I read about this protocol called Aloha, and I would like to make a simple simulator for the Pure version of it.

Although I understand the concepts, I find it difficult to start.

Basically we have a N senders in the network. Each sender wants to send a packet. Now each sender doesn't care if the network is busy or under occupation by some other sender. If it wants to send data, it just sends it.

The problem is that if 2 senders send some data at the same time, then they will both collide and thus both packets will be destroyed.

Since they are destroyed the two senders will need to send again the same packets.

I understand this simple concept, the difficulty is, how to modulate this using probabilities.

Now, I need to find out the throughput which is the rate of (successful) transmission of frames.

Before going any further, we have to make some assumptions:

```
All frames have the same length.
Stations cannot generate a frame while transmitting or trying to transmit. (That is, if a station keeps trying to send a frame, it cannot be allowed to generate more frames to send.)
The population of stations attempts to transmit (both new frames and old frames that collided) according to a Poisson distribution.
```

I can't really understand the third assumption, how will I apply this probability in aloha?
I can't find a single code online in order to get an idea how this would be done...

here is some further information on this protocol:

```
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet#Pure_ALOHA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to split the time into intervals; in each interval a certain number of stations attempts to transmit. This number is the number of events occurring in a fixed interval or time according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution.

You have to model it according to the Poisson distribution.

My 2 cents, hope this helps

Comment: Hi thanks for your help!

but, if I split the time into intervals won't this be a slotted aloha and not a pure aloha?

thanks!

Comment: Change "interval" with "time frame"